# C++ What does the DLL_EXPORT in DLL headers mean?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation

I did the dll tutorial from [codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm). There are the following lines in the header:

```
#if defined DLL_EXPORT
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

But: If I use it as suggested, I get an error during compilation (defined as import). If I exchange dllexport with dllimport and vice versa, it compiles fine and the call from another application works fine. Like this:

```
#if defined DLL_EXPORT
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

Is this an error in the tutorial, or am I missing something?

I use mingw and the gcc-compiler. As some might notice, I asked something similar in the comments there.

Comment: It is just a macro.  It must be #defined when you compile the code for the DLL.  Which ensures that the linker knows that functions declared with DECLDIR are exported.  It must be *not* defined when you compile the code that uses the DLL.  Which ensures that the linker knows that these functions need to be imported.  Inverting it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You probably forgot to define DLL_EXPORT in your preprocessor settings when building the DLL.

Comment: @HansPassant But why does it work with inverting and doesnt work the first way? And the stuff with "must not defined when you compile the code that uses the dll": This relates only to static linking, or doesnt it? Because the header isnt used in dynamic linking.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm more a rookie, so what do you mean? Could you give a short example? I know what a preprocessor does, I know what a macro is, but what do you mean with settings?

Comment: The tutorial should mention that `DLL_EXPORT` must be defined when building the dll and not defined when using the dll. This is an essential part of how the macro works.

Comment: @drescherjm Could you give a simple code example? I still dont know where it has to be defined and defined to what?

Comment: This is not code. It is compiler settings. You need to define `DLL_EXPORT` when building the dll. In Visual Studio you put this in the `c++` preprocessor settings of the project settings. I am not sure what IDE you use with mingw and I do not have much experience with that so it would be difficult for me to instruct you how to add the preprocessor definition for your compiler / ide.

Comment: @drescherjm Ah, so this is IDE dependent. I use NetBeans, but I compile directly using g++ from command line. I understand, that you might not be able to answer my problem properly, so: What should I do, to get a good answer respectively how can I make this into a good question?

Comment: Use -D: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-d.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the article, you linked, in the listing of the first .cpp file, at line 4 is:

```
#define DLL_EXPORT
```

This will insure that when **this** DLL is compiled, it will include this symbol defined and thus use:

```
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
```

In the header file, which will also be included by client projects, there is no such definiation, and thus will use:

```
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
```

This is the correct usage.